# String to Date conversion gives me NA only in R

Tags: r

I seem to be unable to convert my characters into Dates. The conversion gives me no errors but all I get is NA. I have no idea where I am going wrong

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:98, .Label = c("01 2009", "01 2010",
"01 2011", "01 2012", "01 2013", "01 2014", "01 2015", "02 2009",
"02 2010", "02 2011", "02 2012", "02 2013", "02 2014", "02 2015",
"02 2016", "03 2008", "03 2009", "03 2010", "03 2011", "03 2012",
"03 2013", "03 2014", "03 2015", "03 2016", "04 2009", "04 2010",
"04 2011", "04 2012", "04 2013", "04 2014", "04 2015", "04 2016",
"05 2007", "05 2009", "05 2010", "05 2011", "05 2012", "05 2013",
"05 2014", "05 2015", "05 2016", "06 2010", "06 2011", "06 2012",
"06 2013", "06 2014", "06 2016", "07 2008", "07 2009", "07 2010",
"07 2011", "07 2012", "07 2013", "07 2014", "07 2016", "08 2007",
"08 2008", "08 2009", "08 2010", "08 2011", "08 2012", "08 2013",
"08 2014", "08 2015", "08 2016", "09 2007", "09 2009", "09 2010",
"09 2011", "09 2012", "09 2013", "09 2014", "09 2015", "09 2016",
"10 2008", "10 2009", "10 2010", "10 2012", "10 2013", "10 2014",
"10 2015", "10 2016", "11 2007", "11 2008", "11 2009", "11 2010",
"11 2011", "11 2012", "11 2013", "11 2016", "12 2008", "12 2009",
"12 2010", "12 2011", "12 2012", "12 2013", "12 2016", "NA NA"
), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L,
10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 76L)), .Names = c("Date",
"Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -98L), class = "data.frame")


EGOOTimePlot$Date<-as.Date(EGOOTimePlot$Date,format="%m %Y")
```

Comment: Date needs day as well. Use `paste` and then do it i..e `as.Date(paste(EGOOTimePlot$Date, '01'), "%m %Y %d")`

Comment: Agree with @akrun, what you have there are not dates.

Comment: Ugh. Thats not written anywhere- although it probably is in some small print. Thanks

Comment: Or else you can convert to `as.yearmon` from `zoo`

Comment: See _Note_ in `?as.Date`: "If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific. The most common behaviour is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one.". This assumption was apparently not made in your case.